# How to search for a field and confirm it's empty?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm new to Ruby and I've been thrown into the deep end on using it within cucumber to write test suites with very little time to learn it.

I'm trying to write a line of code to check that a field exists on a webpage and that said field is blank.

So far I've got:

```
Then /^I can verify that the fleet field is blank$/ do
  find_by_id('fleet', :text == nil)
end
```

The two features that I have written are:

```
Scenario: US1020-1  Confirm that the Date of Liability field is blank on screen
    When I navigate to the fleet vehicle search screen
    Then I can search for a valid record using Fleet number: "123456"
    And Registration number: "N253CSL"
    Then I can verify that the fleet field is blank


Scenario: US1020-2  Confirm that the Date of Liability field is blank on screen
    When I navigate to the fleet vehicle search screen
    And Registration number: "N253CSL"
    Then I can verify that the fleet field is blank
```

Scenario `US1020 - 1` should fail as I've populated to fleet with with `123456`, but it passes.

N.B.  The ruby code for the other elements of the test, connect to webpage, fill in field are already written and are ok.

Any help for a noob would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Then /^I can verify that the fleet field is blank$/ do
  expect(find_by_id('fleet').value).to be_blank
end
```